# Flutter Firebase : how to read data from firestore as list

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want read all data from firestore collection as list.

I try this :

```
CollectionReference _collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('device');

QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _collectionRef.get();

final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();

print(allData[0]);
```

output :

```
{id: APA91bGot-Hm05aR}
```

i want read only id like this :

```
APA91bGot-Hm05aR
```

Not as Map.

Can i make this without model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => { 
  return (doc.data() as Map)["id"];
}).toList();
```